# Software to take a recorded audio file that contains a person saying a phrase, and then extract each word

Tags: windows, audio

For example to take a 30 second recording of Kermit the From saying "Well folks it has been a whirlwind of an adventure today".  Import that file into the program and tell it to extract any word or set off words as separate audio files.  So if I told it "Whirlwind" it would listen for that part of the audio clip, find it, and then splice it out from everything else, and save it as a single file.

Preferably .ogg, however I can convert into .ogg after.